# PHP5 or PHP7 depending on URL

Tags: php, nginx

I use Ubuntu 14 and want to use PHP5 and PHP7 from the ondrej launchpad at the same time.

The idea was to use PHP5 if the URL matches

```
backend.local/app/*.php
```

and PHP7 (basically using a symlink to the above app folder) if it is

```
backend.local/app-php7/*.php
```

Using this nginx config:

```
    location /app-php7 {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   APPLICATION_ENV local;

            fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   APPLICATION_ENV local;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
    }
```

it returns the error "File not found" when trying to access the app-php7 folder.

nginx error.log:

> [error] 6116#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"
>   while reading response header from upstream.
>
> request: "GET /app-php7/ HTTP/1.1",
>
> upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:",
>
> host:  "backend.local", referrer: "http://backend.local/"

If I replace php5 with php7.0 in the second location phpinfo correctly displays my php7.0 information.

Comment: I think [this](http://serverfault.com/a/757255/265362) answered my question, I'll come back in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Jup, you miss the *.php stuff in the php7 location section.